# NodeJS - How to have express wait for a response?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am working with a very small piece of nodeJS code thats using express. The app receives a payload as a `POST` and sends it to another method which submits it to `kafka`. Once this happens, I need to return a response back to express so that it can close the connection based on the status (return a 200 response for example).

```
// producer.js

// Defined variables
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Producer = kafka.Producer;

module.exports = {

    sendToProducer: function (payload) {

        // Define our kafka settings
        var client = new kafka.KafkaClient(),
            producer = new Producer(client);

        // On producer ready
        producer.on('ready', function () {

            // Send our payload to our topic
            producer.send(payload, function (err, data) {
                console.log(data);
                // Return our response back to `app.js` so express can handle it.
            });

        });

        // On producer error
        producer.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Producer Error', err)
        })
    }

};



// app.js
app.post('/payload', function (req, res) {

    // Define our route
    const payload = req.body;
    const route = payload.route;

    // Check to see if we have a route
    if(!route){
        logError('no route');
    }

    let mappedData = [{ topic: 'test', messages: 'hi... ', partition: 0 }]

    // Based on the route
    switch(route){

        // Receive data
        case 'ingest':
            producer.sendToProducer(mappedData);
            // How can I tell express the status of the above method so that we can close the request? (ex 200 response for example?)
        break;

        // Handle undefined routes
        default:

        break;
    }

});
```

In my `app.js` case statement, how can I wait for a response/callback from `producer.sendToProducer(mappedData);` so that I can handle the express status appropriately ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `sendToProducer()` is a `promise` / `async` function :

```
app.post('/payload', async function (req, res) {

    // Define our route
    const payload = req.body;
    const route = payload.route;

    // Check to see if we have a route
    if(!route){
        logError('no route');
    }

    let mappedData = [{ topic: 'test', messages: 'hi... ', partition: 0 }]

    // Based on the route
    switch(route){

        // Receive data
        case 'ingest':
            await producer.sendToProducer(mappedData);
            // How can I tell express the status of the above method so that we can close the request? (ex 200 response for example?)
        break;

        // Handle undefined routes
        default:

        break;
    }

});
```